# Is it possible to return two view from a single controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I have a Help link which shows static content based on the screen when i click help screen. I have two screens which are exactly the same so i had used the same controller. But the help screen content differs, so kindly let me know if i can get two views from a single controller so that i can use that in getting the appropriate help screen using tiles.

Comment: can you return more than one value from a function ?

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

as you are using tiles hope you know tiles, one of the following approaches can be used

1)

define page layout as same for both the pages in tiles definition.

and define 2 jsp pages for just content and return the appropriate one from controller using if condition check.

add this returned view as a body inside tiles definition so that body comes dynamically.

2) Use same jsp page for both the views and put content dynamically using jsp variables

like ${content} where content is dynamic content added from controller based on if condition.